# File Extension of XSD files

Tags: xml, xsd

Do the XSD (XML schema) files have usually extension .xsd or they can have extension .xml as well?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they should be XSD even if the inside is an XML-like  structured file. You can ususally parse it like an xml. the only difference is that each element name will begin with "xs:" folowed by the element name.

Answer (score 3):

That would be: "**Usually XSD**"

Answer (score 1):

I think .xsd is the most common usage, and there may well be tools such as editors that recognize .xsd files as schema documents and open them accordingly. In general, though, file extensions are a matter of personal preference.